# vscode extensions get file from current folder

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I created file keywords in the same directory where is extension.js
When i try read, it's not finded.

```
    fs.readFile(path.resolve("~/keywords"), 'utf8', (a, b) => {
        if (a) {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage('fail: ', a)
            return
        }
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('ok')            
        words = JSON.parse(b)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

To access files in the same working directory as the script calling them, use:

`('./file.js')`

And to access 1 level below, use:

`('../lib/file.js')`

Comment: You can just use `fs.readFile('./keywords.js')...` instead of `path.resolve(..`

Comment: What extension is `keywords`?

Comment: it's without extension.
I can't even to get file extension.js from extension.js

Comment: why without an extension? can you post all of your code in please?

Comment: Because I don't need extension, it's not important. There is just text.

Comment: what's the directory structure? Are you executing the above code in the same folder as `keywords`? I have a feeling if you literally give it a `.txt` extension it'll work.

Comment: "Are you executing the above code in the same folder as keywords" - Yes
"I have a feeling if you literally give it a .txt extension it'll work" not working

Comment: just as a sanity check, you have `var fs = require('fs')` right..? I've used `fs.readFile('./file.txt', (err, result)...` hundreds of times.